# C# password encoding in Android

Tags: c#, android, encryption, encoding, cryptography

I'm working on academic project with a friend, and my job is to prepare an Android app.
Recently I've encountered an error:
my friend used C# class: `SimpleMembership` and it's method: `CreateUserAndAccount(String, String)` to create user accounts.

Now I have a problem: I can't find the encryption method that is being used in this case. So far it seems it is RFC2898 (PBKDF2), I've found the algorithm to use in Java, but I don't know other credentials such as salt, number of iterations and length.

Comment: **"Anyone could help me?"** : Talk to your friend perhaps? If he/she explains what sort of encryption they used you could probably work it out between you.

Comment: @Squonk that's a bit premature, these kind of technological details are neatly hidden from the user of the libraries (to the point that M$ forgets to explain the protocol, as usual)

Comment: @owlstead : My point was simply that the OP has come here to ask the question instead of discussing it with their friend and trying to do some Internet searches themselves.

Comment: @Squonk That was not that clear to me from the above remark, though I can understand your sentiment. A quick search showed zero effort from Microsoft to explain their methods, fortunately I know that Mono has implemented quite a lot. But if you don't know that, you won't find the protocol that easily. Hence my remark otherwise the question may be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of searching provides the [Mono source code](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs) (which is normally verified against the M$ implementation) and a pointer to [the used method of encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto.hashpassword%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) which should describe what you are looking for.

> The password hash is generated with the RFC 2898 algorithm using a
>   128-bit salt, a 256-bit subkey, and 1000 iterations. The format of the
>   generated hash bytestream is {0x00, salt, subkey}, which is base-64
>   encoded before it is returned.

I'm wondering though why you would need this server side functionality within your Android code though.

Comment: We are working on informatics in economy project in which we are to prepare web (.NET) application and mobile one.

Comment: OK, but are you going to create a user account - on the server - using code on the client?